# r data table subset multiple conditions patterns

Tags: r, data.table, subset

To simplicy I have:

A data.table : `names(DT) <- c("FirstName","BirthDate",otherscolumns)`

Two vectors : `firstname <- c("one","two","three","for")` & `birthdate <- c("1992-01-01","1993-02-02","1994-03-03","1995-04-04")`

The first **firstname** ("one") corresponds to the first **birthdate** ("1992-01-01") and so on. I would like to keep in DT **only the rows matching the right firstname with the right birthdate**. For now I did :

```
data <- DT[FirstName == firstname [1] & BirthDate == birthdate[1] | 
                    FirstName == firstname [2] & BirthDate == birthdate[2] |
                    FirstName == firstname [3] & BirthDate == birthdate[3] | 
                    FirstName == firstname [4] & BirthDate == birthdate[4]]
```

I'm sure there is a best way to do this. I tried generating a string but it didn't work. Indeed, in my real experiment I have more than 4 firstnames and I don't find that copy-past and change the indice is a good way (subjects)

Thanks very much for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `Map` to loop over the 'firstname', 'birthdate', vectors, do a comparison, then `Reduce` with `|` to get a logical vector that can be used for subsetting the data.table

```
library(data.table)
data <- DT[DT[, Reduce(`|`, Map(function(x, y) FirstName == x & 
              BirthDate == y, firstname, birthdate))]]
```